# How to get date time based start value and end value in python

Tags: python

I have string `period = 2022-09-12/2022-09-15`

How can i get `arr = [2022-09-12, 2022-09-13, 2022-09-14, 2022-09-15]`

Thanks

Comment: What part of the problem are you having trouble with? Splitting the string? Turning the parts into dates? Getting a range of dates from that start and end? Putting the result in a list? What actually is in that list? Strings and you forgot the quotes, or datetime values? Share your code and be specific, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm newbie in python
And  i don't have solution for this problem
Sorry if my question is unclear

Comment: Oh, that's one way of going about it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify what part of the problem you're struggling with, here's a solution for the whole thing:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

text = '2022-09-12/2022-09-15'


def date_range(start, end):
    # this function takes two dates and generates all the dates in the range
    for d in range((end - start).days + 1):
        yield start + timedelta(days=d)


# defining the format your dates come in (and in which you may want them)
format = '%Y-%m-%d'

# this is the answer, using the above function
dates = list(date_range(*map(lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, format), text.split('/'))))
print(dates)

# taking the `dates` result, you can of course format them as strings:
print([datetime.strftime(d, format) for d in dates])
```

Output:

```
[datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 15, 0, 0)]
['2022-09-12', '2022-09-13', '2022-09-14', '2022-09-15']
```

On the key expression:

```
list(date_range(*map(lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, format), text.split('/'))))
```

The function is a generator, so there's a `list()` around it to exhaust the generator into a list.

The `map()` takes a function, in this case a lambda and applies it to all elements of an iterable, in this case `text.split('/')`, which is just the two date strings in your original text.

The lambda takes those two parts and parses them into actual datetime using `datetime.strptime(d, format)`, so the `map()` yields the two dates.

The `*` then spreads those into the function call to `date_range()`, providing the dates as arguments.

Note: if this also needs to work for a descending range of dates, for example `'2022-09-15/2022-09-12'`, you can use this instead (which works for either):

```
def date_range(start, end):
    days = (end - start).days
    sign = -1 if days < 0 else 1
    for d in range(0, days + sign, sign):
        yield start + timedelta(days=d)
```

Comment: This solve my solution,
Love you

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 12)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 15)

involved_dates = []
for i in range((end_date - start_date).days):
    involved_dates.append(start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i))
```

Comment: You may have problems if the months are different. Edit: no sorry :(

Comment: i run this and get this value ```[datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 14, 0, 0)]```
But you can format value in array like 2022-09-22.
Thanks so much